# What am I doing wrong on trying to set data to Struct

Tags: swift, struct

I'm trying to create a Struct to be able to pass data between screens. However, when I set data to my Struct properties and then I try to use it in another screen I got the value as "nil". What am I doing wrong?

**Objects Struct:**

```
import UIKit

struct Objetos {
    var nome: String
    var foto: UIImage
}
```

**That's how I'm trying to set the value:**

```
var objeto = Objeto(nome: "", foto: UIImage())

@IBAction func botaoAdcItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (self.namePreview!.text != nil) && (self.imagePreview!.image != nil) {
       objeto?.nome = self.namePreview.text!
       objeto?.foto = self.imagePreview.image!

       self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else { return }
}
```

**That's how I'm trying to read the data:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {
     @IBOutlet weak var itensTableView: UITableView!
     var arrayNomes = NSMutableArray()

     var objeto: Objetos?
     var objetos = [Objetos]()

        //TableView
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

          for nome in objetos {
              arrayNomes.add(nome)
          }
          return arrayNomes.count //Nil value
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
          cell.nameCell.text = objeto?.nome //Nil value                    
          cell.imageViewCell.image = objeto?.foto //Nil value
          return cell
     }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          self.itensTableView.reloadData()
     }
```

***Storyboard:***

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you have some very confusing variable names. You have `var objetos: Objetos?` in one class and `var objetos = [Objetos]()` in another. Use `objeto` for one and use `objetos` for an array. And rename your `Objetos` struct to `Objeto` since it represents just one.

Comment: Hello rmaddy! I agree with you, just did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you want to set the data to the previous VC

```
// ! won't crash
let count = self.navigationController.viewControllers!.count
let tab = self.navigationController.viewControllers![count-2] as! UITabBarController
let vc = tab.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController
vc.objetos.append(Objetos(name:self.namePreview.text!,foto:self.imagePreview.image!))
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

plus

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let item = objectos[indexPath.row]
   let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
   cell.nameCell.text = item.nome //Nil value                    
   cell.imageViewCell.image = item.foto //Nil value
   return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return objetos.count
}
```

Comment: Hello Sh_Khan! Should I implement that where I'm trying to set the value, correct?However, how can I read it?

Comment: Do you fill a form in the secondVC and want to reload the table with it in the FirstVC ? , if so append this content of **objectos** array  and access it in viewDidAppear of the previous VC

Comment: Probably because It's also embed in a tabbar controller?

Comment: isn't it the previous of the one you pop from ?? also do you cast it to **ViewController** class

Comment: That's correct at the moment the app has only 2 screens. I also casted to ViewController class

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1b4fc5190) to 'Cade__Minhas_Coisas.ViewController' (0x102393af0).
2018-07-06 21:10:52.275955-0300 Cadê Minhas Coisas[449:88251] Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1b4fc5190) to 'Cade__Minhas_Coisas.ViewController' (0x102393af0).

Comment: where **ViewController** position in hierarchy ??

Comment: I just posted a Storyboard picture, can you check?

Comment: Dude, it worked perfectly!! However, It's kinda complicated to understand. There's no other way a little bit simple to do that?

Comment: you can use delegate pattern

Comment: Good morning, can you recommend me a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

In your second code snippet, you never initialize `objetos` to anything. Thus, when you try to set one of the properties on `objetos`, nothing happens, because `objetos` doesn't exist.

Solution: Initialize `objetos` before trying to use it.

Comment: Hello Charles! Could you give me an example using my code, please?

Comment: @rmaddy The first snippet is just the type declaration.

Comment: @TituJow Instead of `var objetos:Objectos?`, try something like `var objetos = Objectos(name: /* some default value */, foto: /* some default value */)`. Alternatively, just reassign `objetos` in your second snippet instead of `objetos?.etc` using the form described above.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yeah, I meant the 1st after the type declaration thinking you meant the 2nd aster the declaration.

Comment: Hello! I'm initializing, however I still getting a nil value. I also updated the question, could you check please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
var objetos:Objetos?
```

with

```
var objeto = Objetos(nome: "", foto: UIImage())
```

you are starting your object as optional, and thus from the start is nil. When you try to assign properties in your struct you are failures because the object from the beginning is nonexistent

Regarding you other nil values, here is a revised view of your snippet

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var itensTableView: UITableView!

        var objetos = [Objetos]()

        //TableView
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return objetos.count
        }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
                let objeto = objectos[indexPath.row]
                cell.nameCell.text = objeto.nome                    
                cell.imageViewCell.image = objeto.foto
                return cell
        }


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                self.itensTableView.reloadData()
            }
```

In your `Additional Novo Itens Vc` you are going to need to pass the created data back to your original View Controller, one way to do this is

```
@IBAction func botaoAdcItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (self.namePreview!.text != nil) && (self.imagePreview!.image != nil) {
       // create the objecto 
       var objeto = Objetos(nome: namePreview.text, 
                            foto: imagePreview.image)

       // create a reference to your previous view controller
       let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as! ViewController
       // add objecto to objectos
       vc.objetos.append(objeto)

       self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    } 

    else { return }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your code, but I still getting "nil"  when I try to use it

Comment: where do you get nil?

Comment: I got nil on tableview methods

Comment: can you be more specific? are you reffering to `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Yeah, both. I heard that I can make it by using delegate pattern, is it better?

Comment: In this snippet of code I dont see where you are assigning `objetos`? could you share the part of the code as well?

Comment: Please, check the second code snippet. I updated showing the way I'm setting the data